# swift stack variable disposal/lifetime

Tags: swift

When an object similar to 'alert' in the example below will be released?

```
 func showMessage() {
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!, completionHandler: messageHandler)
    }
```

Will it be destroyed right after the ending brace or it can be added to some autorelease pool similarly to Objective-C and destroyed later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are destroyed when nobody holds a reference to them.

When you call beginSheetModalForWindow, the alert will be displayed on the screen in a modal way, and that will hold a reference until some point after the completion handler has been called, and the alert is removed from the display. So there is no need to worry about it and no need to try and hold another reference.

Without the call to beginSheetModalForWindow, the alert would be gone at the end of your function. But without that call, that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As @gnasher729 says, objects stick around as long as there is at least one remaining strong reference to them.

In your example, the beginSheetModalForWindow call causes the system to take ownership of the alert, so everything is fine. The system manages the alert, and when it's done with it, it gets freed.

Here's an example that's **not** ok: (adding a view controller's view as a subview of the current view controller's view hierarchy)

```
func addViewContents() 
{
  let vc = NSViewController(nibName: @"specialView" bundle: nil)
  currentViewController.view.addSubview(vc.view) 
}
```

In this example, we create a new instance of a view controller by loading a nibfile called "specialView". This creates a view controller object. We then add the view controller's **view** to our view controller's view hierarchy, but don't keep a strong reference to the view controller. When the method above returns, the `vc` variable goes out of scope and there are no more strong references to the view controller, so it gets deallocated. Now our view hierarchy has a new subview that was created by a view controller that no longer exists. If any button `IBActions` on that new subview used to point to the view controller, they now point to nowhere, and the app will crash if you trigger the action.

In this example you should add the newly created view controller as a child view controller of the windows' main view controller. That way the new view controller's parent has a strong reference to it and it won't be deallocated.